# File download using RichFaces

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces

I got the following to work already:

1. User can upload a file (i.e. a compressed archive)
2. User can uncompress the file on the server
3. User can execute some stuff on these files, which results in more files to be generated

Now I need to get step 4 to work:

- User can download the files to his own computer again

Can anyone give me a hint? I tried to understand the stuff I found on Google, but it does not work quite as expected. Do I have to set a content type? When I set application/octet stream only txt and csv files would display correctly (in the browser, not as download popup as I wanted) other files would not work...

JSP:

```
<a4j:commandLink value="Download" action="#{appController.downloadFile}" rendered="#{!file.directory}">
   <f:param name="file" value="#{file.absoluteFilename}" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

appController:

```
public String downloadFile() {
    String filename = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("file");
    File file = new File(filename);
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();  

    writeOutContent(response, file, file.getName());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    return null;
}

private void writeOutContent(final HttpServletResponse res, final File content, final String theFilename) {
    if (content == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + theFilename);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(content);
        ServletOutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();
        int bt = fis.read();
        while (bt != -1) {
            os.write(bt);
            bt = fis.read();
        }
        os.flush();
        fis.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (final IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ApplicationController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your concrete problem is that you're attempting to download files by Ajax. This is not correct. JavaScript can't deal with binary responses nor has it any facilities to force a *Save As* dialogue. You need to make it a normal synchronous request instead so that it's the webbrowser itself who has to deal with it.

```html
<h:commandLink value="Download" action="#{appController.downloadFile}" rendered="#{!file.directory}">
   <f:param name="file" value="#{file.absoluteFilename}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

As to setting the content type, if you have a file name with extension at your hands, you could use `ServletContext#getMimeType()` to resolve it based on `<mime-mapping>` in `web.xml` (either the server's default one or your webapp's one).

```
ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) externalContext.getContext();
String contentType = servletContext.getMimeType(file.getName());

if (contentType == null) {
    contentType = "application/octet-stream";
}

response.setContentType(contentType);
// ...
```

*(note that I assume that you're using JSF 1.x, seeing the way how you obtained the servlet response, you could since JSF 2.x otherwise also use `ExternalContext#getMimeType()`)*

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the correct mimetype - I was tempted to accept this as answer, but Luiggi wrote a slightly better solution.

Comment: I don't see how it's better than what you already have so far in your question.

Comment: I tend to accept more verbose answers if I have to decide between 2 of otherwise equal quality

Comment: Equal quality? His answer contains bad code and based on your next question you didn't seem to use his code at all.

Answer (score 4):

I have done the step 4 some weeks ago, and let me give you some advices:

1. Use a link html tag component. For this, I recommend the `a4j:htmlCommandLink` tag component (it's like the common `h:commandLink` with the difference that the `<f:param />` components are always rendered, you can check more in the [component documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_htmlCommandLink.html)).
2. If you don't know the type of the file to download (), then you must set the Content as **application/octet-stream**.
3. After setting up the file to download to your response, you should set that the response has been completed.

I'll put my Backing Bean code for this request:

```
public void descargaArchivo() {
    //sorry but the programming standard says that we MUST declare
    //our variables at the beginning of any function =(
    HttpServletResponse objResponse;
    FileInputStream objFileInputStream;
    String strNombreCompletoArchivo, strNombreArchivo;
    byte[] arrDatosArchivo;
    try {
        //Here I get the <f:param> with the full name of the file. It encapsulates
        // the Faces.getCurrentInstance...  call.
        strNombreCompletoArchivo = UManejadorSesionWeb.obtieneParametro("nombreCompletoArchivo");
        //The function obtieneNombreArchivo retrieves the name of the file
        //based on the full name and the file separator (/ for Windows, \ for Linux)
        strNombreArchivo = UFuncionesGenerales.obtieneNombreArchivo(strNombreCompletoArchivo);
        //Getting the response from Faces.getCurrentInstance... 
        objResponse = UManejadorSesionWeb.obtieneHttpResponse();
        //Setting up the response content type and header (don't set the length!)
        objResponse.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        objResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + strNombreArchivo + "\"");
        //Create the FileInputStream for the file to download
        objFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(strNombreCompletoArchivo);
        //Setting the file on the response
        arrDatosArchivo = new byte[UConstante.BUFFER_SIZE];
        while(objFileInputStream.read(arrDatosArchivo, 0, UConstante.BUFFER_SIZE) != -1) {
           objResponse.getOutputStream().write(arrDatosArchivo, 0, UConstante.BUFFER_SIZE);
        }
        objFileInputStream.close();
        objResponse.getOutputStream().flush();
        objResponse.getOutputStream().close();
        //Telling the framework that the response has been completed.
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (Exception objEx) {
        //manage the errors...
    }
}
//The constant used for byte array size
public class UConstante {
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
}
```

The jsp fragment I used looks like this:

```
<a4j:htmlCommandLink  rendered="#{documento.rutaDestino != null}"
    action="#{documentoRequerido.descargaArchivo}">
    <f:param name="nombreCompletoArchivo" value="#{documento.rutaDestino}" />
    <h:graphicImage value="/Resource/iconos/mover-abajo.png" styleClass="pic" />
</a4j:htmlCommandLink>
```

Hope this helps you.

EDIT: I had some spare time, sorry but we are kinda busy in the project. The Java code was updated and tested in IE8, Firefox 9 and 10, and Chrome 16. For the value of buffer size constant, I did some research and found a good answer in [this](http://geekomatic.ch/2009/12/29/1262124900000.html) site.

P.S.: I don't take this as a competition, I just try to help people when I can. If my code is not good then thanks for letting me know it, that's the better way for everyone to grow better and healthy :).

---

EDIT: Thanks to @lisa

To achieve the following manually, just changing this part in the snippet

```
//strNombreCompletoArchivo = UManejadorSesionWeb.obtieneParametro("nombreCompletoArchivo");
String parameterStr = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap.get("nombreCompletoArchivo");
strNombreCompletoArchivo = parameterStr;
```

Comment: @BalusC [FileInputStream#available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#available()): "Returns the number of bytes that can be read from this file input stream without blocking" I dont see why it doesn't do what I think. By the way, when I did my requirement I have looked in your solution and mixed with other solutions I found in the web. Plus, you give the core answer to him, file download can't be done with AJAX.

Comment: In other words, it does not necessarily return the **total** number of bytes which can be read from the stream.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I could make a loop and pass the file by fragments of `byte[]`s like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-download-file-from-website-java-jsp/) link shows.

Comment: This does not seem to work with IE8, any hints? (yes, we already use IE compatibility mode)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the richfaces a4j:commandLink tag for the download, the standard jsf tag h:commandLink would be enough.

Then make sure you have the following headers set on your response (you can check with firebug in firefox):

> Content-Disposition   attachment; filename="your_file_name.xxx"
>
> Content-Type  application/xxx
>
> Content-Length    1234

Content-Length: number of bytes.